# React-router-dom, route component not render

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i want to create a tab using **react-router-dom**.
so in my parent route, i set my route to the profile page.

```
<Router history={history}>
     <div>
       <Route path="/profile" exact component={ProfilePageComponent}/>
    </div>
</Router>
```

then, in my **ProfilePageComponent**, i set the child route

```
<div className="profile-page-container">
   <div className="height-controler">
      <SidebarProfileComponent/>
      <Switch>
          <Route path={`/profile/change-password`} component={ChangePasswordComponent}/>
      </Switch>
   </div>        
</div>
```

when i go to the **/profile** path, the **SidebarProfileComponent** is showing but the ChangePasswordComponent isnt showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an `exact attribute` defined on the parent route, when you visit `/profile/change-password`, the parent Route itself doesn't match and hence there is no question of the child route matching.

If you remove the exact prop from the parent route, `/profile` matches `/profile/change-password` and hence `ProfileComponent` gets rendered and then the child Route is matched

Remove the exact prop from parent

```
<Router history={history}>
     <div>
       <Route path="/profile" component={ProfilePageComponent}/>
    </div>
</Router>
```

> P.S. Always remember if you have nested Routes, you must not use exact
>   attribute, instead use `Switch` component for multiple Routes